# RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, remotewebdriver

I'm trying to take a screenshot with RemoteWebDriver of [Winium.Desktop](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/wiki).
As RemoteWebDriver does not implement TakesScreenshot I declared the object as WebDriver.

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteUrl), desiredCapabilities);

WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

When I try to cast it to I get:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot

When I print the driver class name I get RemoteWebDriver although it was declared as WebDriver.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `Augmenter` class? and what does the method `augment` do? I couldn't find it in Winium repo...

Comment: It is part of Selenium Remote package, Winium is the Windows driver. see https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/Augmenter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RemoteWebDriver` does implement `TakesScreenshot`, `WebDriver` does not. So maybe you can get rid of the cast and it'll solve your problem, though it's very weird you get that exception. My guess is that it's probably because Winium's implementation of RemoteWebDriver isn't complete.

However, if you tried checking the class name with `getClass()` during runtime, it resolves to the runtime class of the instance, that's why you get `RemoteWebDriver`...

So to me it seems like a **defect** in Winium.

Comment: Well, it's probably a bug, and you should open an issue in their GitHub. I saw that they do implement the command execution of taking a screenshot in their Winium.Desktop.Driver.

Comment: The solution was to use `getScreenshotAs()` from the `RemoteWebDriver` object.
The method is not implemented in Selenium 2.39.0, I had to upgrade to  2.53.1 and got the screenshot functionality.
The [Selenium Docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#remotewebdriver) are confusing as they're instructing to use the `Augmenter()` .
There is no problem with [Winium.Dekstop](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

RemoteWebDriver class does not implement TakesScreenshot class. It implements **ITakesScreenshot** interface along with other interfaces and this interface has GetScreenshot method. So change the type casting to **ITakeScreenshot**.

I hope this should work for you.

Comment: There's no such interface in Java, this interface is related to c#